# Database DMLOptions and Apex Error Messages

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation, exception

We found an issue when portal users leave comments on our cases. Email notifications to the case owners were not being sent. So I did change the code to use the setoptions method.

The problem is that now, validation messages (validation rules triggered) are not showing on the page. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
List<CaseComment> toInsert = new List<CaseComment>();

for (CaseComment newCom : newComments) {

    if (newCom.CommentBody! = null)  {
        newCom.parentId = cId;
        newCom.IsPublished = true;
        toInsert.add(newCom);                        
    }
}

try  {

    Database.DMLOptions dlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
    dlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
    database.insert(toInsert, dlo);   

} catch(DmlException ex) {

    ApexPages.addMessages(ex);

}
```

Comment: The validation messages not triggering may not be down to an exception, although they well could be. I'd also recommend interrogating the debug logs to see what's going on.

Comment: The debug logs say that a validation rule failed but there is no error message displayed. The comment is not added as expected but no error message is displayed. If I remove the database/dml options and use just the INSERT, it works fine (but no notification is sent).

Comment: Is the validation rule configured to display the message next to a field, rather than on top of the page. Maybe why it can't display the message ?

Comment: Is it standard validation or custom?

Comment: @techtrekker: This validation rule displayed before I added the DMLOptions. So I don't think it's related to where it's configured to display.

Comment: @MohithKumar It's a standard validation rule.

Comment: <apex:messages> .can you try with this tag too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
if (newCom.CommentBody!=null)
        {
            newCom.parentId=cId;
            newCom.IsPublished = true;

            Database.DMLOptions dmo = new database.DMLOptions();
        dmo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
        newCom.setOptions(dmo);
            toInsert.add(newCom);


        }
    }

   try{

 Insert ToInsert;  
   }
catch(DMLException ex){

    ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this if you are using apex pagemessage tag?`

```
<apex:pageMessages id="apexmsg"/>
```

---

method code

```
catch(DMLException e1) {
ApexPages.addMessages(e1);
 }   catch(Exception e2) {
// uh-oh, something else happened bad, better show it to the user
ApexPages.addMessage(
  new ApexPages.Message(
      ApexPages.Severity.ERROR
    , 'Unknown exception while inserting your list of stuff.  Please contact support. Exception: ' + e
  )
);
}
```

Comment: usually you can just catch the DML Exception and do nothing since the system automatically displays most validation errors in the page message components (you're will repeat the same issue), but you'll still want to catch other types exceptions to prevent them in a user frindly fashion , see https://gist.github.com/4048738 for an example

Comment: Thanks guys. Apologies for not replying. I will try this when I get a chance and provide feedback.

Comment: @MohithKumar: I am using that tag in my VF page. Unfortunately, this didn't work. I believe it's related to the database method instead but I cannot understand why. This works if I remove the database options.